# Static Binding works compiled but not under designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

The following code works fine when compiled but I can't get the **Text="{x:Static local:SomeClass+Limits.Name}"** to work in the designer.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks....

```
namespace StaticTest
{
    public class SomeClass 
    {
        public static class Limits
        {
            public const string Name = "It Works!";
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window
    x:Class="StaticTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StaticTest"
    Title="StaticTest"
    Height="146"
    Width="296"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Text="{x:Static local:SomeClass+Limits.Name}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: `x:Static` is *not* a binding.

Answer (score 0):

You need a binding as @H.B. says:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:SomeClass+Limits.Name}}"/>
```

The VS2010 designer can't handle this, but it works fine in VS11 beta.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, it didn't compile in the designer (although it does run if I press F5), saying "Type 'local:SomeClass+Limits' was not found."

Comment: @lsb, it works for me, but maybe because I'm using VS1l beta.  I'll try it in VS2010 tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  As it turns out you need to do something like the following:

```
using System;

namespace StaticTest
{
    public abstract class AbstractViewModel<VM, LC>
        where VM : new()
        where LC : new()
    {
        public AbstractViewModel()
        {
            Limits = new LC();
        }

        static AbstractViewModel()
        {
            Instance = new VM();
        }

        public LC Limits { get; private set; }

        public static VM Instance { get; private set; }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel :
        AbstractViewModel<MainWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel.LimitsClass>
    {
        public class LimitsClass
        {
            public LimitsClass()
            {
                Lots = new MinMax<int>(1, 10);
            }

            public MinMax<int> Lots { get; private set; }
        }        
    }
}


<Window
    x:Class="StaticTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StaticTest"
    Title="StaticTest"
    Height="146"
    Width="296"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindowViewModel.Instance}, Path=Limits.Lots.MaxValue}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```